# Scrapy crawl list of links

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am crawling a page and got a list of links from the hrefs

```
['www.fundsupermart.co.in/main/fundinfo/viewFund.svdo?sedolnumber=SDM0347','www.fundsupermart.co.in/main/fundinfo/viewFund.svdo?sedolnumber=SDM0346', 'www.fundsupermart.co.in/main/fundinfo/viewFund.svdo?sedolnumber=AXS0229' ....]
```

Is it possible to crawl these links from the same spider? its like crawling another link while a crawler is already crawling a link. I don't need the code just a little guideline that how it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [CrawlSpider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider) and define appropriate rules for the list of links?